# Getting error installing nodejs when building from docker

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker

I am trying to install nodejs using the docker console for ubuntu but I get an error installing node js. This is the error I am getting

```
The command [/bin/sh -c ./configure && make && make install] returned a non-zero code: 127
```

This is part of my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
RUN mkdir -p /dir/subdir
RUN apt-get update

# Install nodejs
ADD http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64.tar.gz /dir
WORKDIR /dir/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64
RUN ./configure && make && make install
WORKDIR /dir
```

Comment: Why don't you just install wget before `RUN wget`?

Comment: wget is already installed. I am not really that familiar with docker, Do I need to install it from my dockerfile?

Comment: wget needs to be installed inside of the container, not on your host machine.  You should put the following before the wget line: `RUN apt-get install -y wget`.

Comment: I know this is unrelated to my original question but do you know what error code 2 means? it has to do with RUN cd/node ... ./config
    returned a non-zero code: 2

Comment: You can also use ADD to download the source directly, instead RUN wget. Like `ADD http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64.tar.gz /dir/`

Comment: I updated my question. It seems now that it cant run ./configure 
Im assuming it has to do something with directories but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exit code 127 typically means "command not found". Chances are build-essentials are not installed.

Try adding the following after the apt-get update:

```
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential
```

Comment: make sure all the prequisites are installed before trying to invoke the ./configurre && make && make install https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation#prerequisites